# How to perform bitwise operations with dart List<Int8List>.?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am using Dart `Int8List` in place of `byte` type(Java). I want to do bitwise operations with `Int8List`. But bitwise operations aren't defined in `Int8List`class. How to solve this.?

My block of code for your reference :

```
List<Int8List> myList;
    int offset = 0;  
    
    int read16Bit() {
        int x = ((myList[offset] & 0xFE) << 8) | 
                 (myList[offset+1] & 0xFE);
        offset += 2;
        return x;
    }
```

Comment: You can access an individual byte with `operator []` (e.g. `list[index]`), do your bitwise operation on that byte (and write it back to the list if necessary).  If that's insufficient, please provide more details about what you want to do.

Comment: @jamesdlin - I have  added my block of code in the question description. Please look into that. When I write that, IDE says "The operator '&' isn't defined for the class 'Int8List'."

Comment: `myList` isn't an `Int8List`.  it's a `List<Int8List>` (a list of lists).  Consequently, `myList[offset]` doesn't return a byte and instead returns a *list* of bytes.  Is that what you intended?

Comment: @jamesdlin you are correct. I am working on lists only. On top of them I want to do bitwise operations.

Comment: As I explained, you can do bitwise operations on individual *bytes*.  Operating on a list of lists instead of on a single `Int8List` (or `Uint8List`) seems kind of weird, but if you actually want a list of lists, then you'll need to dereference *twice* to get a byte: `myList[majorIndex][minorIndex] & 0xFE`.